# Best way to call a class that can be called from multiple places

Tags: python, class, factory, instantiation

I have a factory class and a UI that calls this class, but this class can be initially instantiated from multiple places in the UI, so I have stored the factoryObject in the UI class and for each function that can instantiate the factory class I have done

```
if not self.factoryObject:
    self.factoryObject = MyFactoryClass()
```

Is this good coding practise, or is there a better way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to have multiple separate instances of the factory class? If not, just create a global singleton and use that everywhere:

```
factory = Factory()
```

Otherwise, all of the options below allow you to write code like:

```
ui = UI()
ui.factory.make_stuff()
```

so you can easily switch between these method if desired.

OK, you need separate factory instances. But do you need a separate instance for each instance of the UI class? If not:

```
class UI(object):
    factory = Factory()
```

OK, you need one factory per UI instance. Is it expensive to make a factory? Do you often have UI instances that never use a factory? Have you measured a performance problem? If the answer to any of these is no, you can probably just create a factory when you create a UI:

```
class UI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.factory = Factory()
```

Finally, the answer to your question, if you really want to lazily instantiate a factory:

```
class UI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._factory = None

    @property
    def factory(self):
        if self._factory is None:
            self._factory = Factory()
        return self._factory
```

The `@property` decorator will allow you to write `ui.factory`.

If you find yourself often writing this kind of pattern in your classes and are tired of it, consider the third party [cached_property](https://github.com/pydanny/cached-property) package:

```
from cached_property import cached_property

class UI(object):

    @cached_property
    def factory(self):
        return Factory()
```